# Why does detaching object from the EntityFramework DbContext sets a null to a navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two classes maped to db tables with EF:

```
public class Relation
{
    // some properties

    public Address MainAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    // some properties
}
```

In a method I do the following:

```
    public Relation AddRelation(Relation relation)
    {
        var dbRelation = this.DbContext.Set<Relation>().Create();
        dbRelation.MainAddress = this.DbContext.Set<Address>().Create();

        // this one copies properties from one instance to another
        this.Copy(relation, dbRelation); 

        dbRelation.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        dbRelation.MainAddress.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        dbRelation.MainAddress.RelationId = dbRelation.Id;

        this.Add(dbRelation);

        this.Context.SaveChanges();

        // before detaching dbRelation.MainAddress != null
         this.Context.Entry<Relation>(dbRelation).State = EntityState.Detached;

        // afterwards dbRelation.MainAddress == null

        return dbRelation;
    }
```

I want to use dbRelation detached from the context.
But the dbRelation.MainAddress gets a null assigned after executing the Detach.

My question is: Why null is there?
What should I do to change this behavior?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why? I just ran into this.

Comment: Nope, @JoeyEng . I think I assumed that this must be by design.

Comment: Thanks, yea that's what I found in another answer as well.